# Learning resources for computational plasma physics

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, plasma-physics, fusion

I'd like to try implementing a "simple" simulation of nuclear fusion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fuel_cycle) process taking place inside an idealized reactor. Are there any good resources (books, courses, papers, blog posts etc.) covering this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this summer as a part of the summer program I've worked on a plasma simulation code [PIConGPU](http://www.hzdr.de/db/Cms?pOid=31887&pNid=0) and my mentor recommended me [Plasma Physics via Computer Simulation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750310251), it is comprehensive introduction to the field. It has all the details need to write your first simulation. :)